# Finding the Checksum Algorithm in this Serial Communication

Tags: checksum

Got a brainteaser for you!  :)

I am working on trying to figuring out this serial communication between a microcontroller and a PC for several months and cannot seem to do it.  9600,N81 and I get no frame errors with my capture tool.

Hopefully someone out there can see these samples and it will click with them.

**Sample 1**

```
    337795, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x62,0x0,0x0,0xA2,0xDE,0xF3,0x75,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    337862,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x63,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x2C,0x92,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    338923, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x63,0x0,0x0,0x7E,0x84,0xF3,0x75,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    338990,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x64,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xD,0xC5,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    340051, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x64,0x0,0x0,0x7B,0x8,0xF3,0x75,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    340118,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x65,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xB6,0xD9,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    340499, IN,0xF0,0x0,0x65,0x5,0x3,0x1,0x1,0x0,0xAB,0xD3,0xF3,0x54,0xF3,  Bytes = 12    
340572,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x66,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x7B,0xFC,0xF3,0xF0,0x5,0x66,0x3,0x4,0x4,0x1,0x8,0x3,0x2F,0x9E,0xF3,0xF3,  Bytes = 21
    340665, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x66,0x0,0x0,0xC3,0xBD,0xF3,0xAB,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    340731,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x67,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xC0,0xE0,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    341794, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x67,0x0,0x0,0x1F,0xE7,0xF3,0xAB,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    341860,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x68,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x39,0x52,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    342923, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x68,0x0,0x0,0xD8,0xAD,0xF3,0xAB,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    342989,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x69,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x82,0x4E,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    344052, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x69,0x0,0x0,0x4,0xF7,0xF3,0xAB,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    344118,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x6A,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x4F,0x6B,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    345180, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x6A,0x0,0x0,0x60,0x18,0xF3,0xAB,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    345246,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x6B,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xF4,0x77,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    345627, IN,0xF0,0x0,0x6B,0x5,0x3,0x1,0x1,0x0,0x9,0xEA,0xF3,0x54,0xF3,  Bytes = 12
    345700,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x6C,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xD5,0x20,0xF3,0xF0,0x5,0x6C,0x3,0x4,0x4,0x1,0x8,0x3,0x78,0x77,0xF3,0xF3,  Bytes = 21
```

**Sample 2**

```
    371435, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x8C,0x0,0x0,0x18,0xC7,0xF3,0x1A,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    371502,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x8D,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xE4,0x88,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    372563, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x8D,0x0,0x0,0xC4,0x9D,0xF3,0x1A,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    372630,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x8E,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x29,0xAD,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    373692, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x8E,0x0,0x0,0xA0,0x72,0xF3,0x1A,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    373758,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x8F,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x92,0xB1,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    374820, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x8F,0x0,0x0,0x7C,0x28,0xF3,0x1A,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    374887,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x90,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xCA,0xC0,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    375949, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x90,0x0,0x0,0x2E,0xE7,0xF3,0x1A,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    376015,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x91,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x71,0xDC,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    376396, IN,0xF0,0x0,0x91,0x5,0x3,0x1,0x1,0x0,0xA4,0x3,0xF3,0xFD,0xF3,  Bytes = 12
    376469,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x92,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xBC,0xF9,0xF3,0xF0,0x5,0x92,0x3,0x4,0x4,0x1,0x8,0x3,0x8,0x66,0xF3,0xF3,  Bytes = 21
    376562, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x92,0x0,0x0,0x96,0x52,0xF3,0xA4,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    376628,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x93,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x7,0xE5,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    377692, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x93,0x0,0x0,0x4A,0x8,0xF3,0xA4,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    377758,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x94,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x26,0xB2,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    378820, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x94,0x0,0x0,0x4F,0x84,0xF3,0xA4,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    378887,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x95,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x9D,0xAE,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    379949, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x95,0x0,0x0,0x93,0xDE,0xF3,0xA4,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    380015,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x96,0x0,0x1,0x1,0x50,0x8B,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    381077, IN,0xF0,0x5,0x96,0x0,0x0,0xF7,0x31,0xF3,0xA4,0xF3,  Bytes = 9
    381144,OUT,0xF0,0x5,0x97,0x0,0x1,0x1,0xEB,0x97,0xF3,0xF0,0xF3,  Bytes = 10
    381523, IN,0xF0,0x0,0x97,0x5,0x3,0x1,0x1,0x0,0x5E,0x1B,0x5B,0xF3,0xF3,  Bytes = 12
```

I have more, if desired.

Some observations I've been able to see -

- First, the numbers at the begging are aggregate timings in I think
  nanoseconds.  The 33* is 33 seconds.
- Beginning byte 0xF0
- Ending byte 0xF3
- Sequence byte, the third byte of every packet increments by 1
- It seems the destination device (noted as OUT) increments first and the
  host (noted as IN) follows..
- For the most part OUT packets are 10 bytes and IN packets are 9 bytes.
- There are some times when this is not true and the packet can be 21 bytes..
- Although I do notice a begin byte and end byte next to each other in the string of 21 bytes, the third byte (sequence#) does not increment.
- I am not sure how to understand these longer packets.
- This is a point to point communication, there are no other devices connected between these 2.
- It is very chatty.

During my testing and probing, my test leads slipped between a couple of pins and killed the microcontroller.   Thinking it would be a great project (and it is), I am attempting to recreate the functions of the original microcontroller.    Which, I pretty much have done with the exception of the communication, figuring out what they are talking about and the checksum. I assume the second to the last byte is the checksum.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By omitting the begin (0xF0) and end (0xF3) bytes, Reversed CRC-CCITT is used to calculate the checksum.

Thanks to this website, I pasted in the bytes and found it - https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/